# Newton's Method stalls upon reaching feasible point

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, newton-raphson

I'm implementing Newton's Method to solve a nonlinear program with general equality constraints, i.e.

\begin{equation}
\underset{\mathbf{x}}{max} \ f(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
s.t \ \ \mathbf h(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation*}

The Lagrangian is given by:

\begin{equation*}
\underset{\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\lambda}}{max} \ 
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
= f(\mathbf{x}) + \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x} + \Delta \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
\approx f(\mathbf{x}) + \nabla f (\mathbf{x})^T \Delta \mathbf{x}
 + \frac{1}{2} \Delta \mathbf{x}^T H(\mathbf{x}) \Delta \mathbf{x}
+ \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T (\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x}) + J(\mathbf{x}) \Delta \mathbf{x})
\end{equation*}

In each iteration, we solve the first order conditions of the Lagrangian, shown below:

\begin{equation}
H(\mathbf{x}) \Delta \mathbf{x} + J(\mathbf{x})^T \boldsymbol{\lambda}
= -\nabla f (\mathbf{x})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
J(\mathbf{x}) \Delta \mathbf{x} = -\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})
\end{equation*}

**Question:**
When $\mathbf{x}$ reaches a feasible point, i.e. $\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$, then the solution to the second first-order condition above will yield $\Delta \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, especially if $J$ has full rank, and the algorithm fails to make any progress.  How do you resolve this?

I'm specifically testing my algorithm on problem #6 in [Test Examples for Nonlinear Programming Codes](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/test_problem_coll.pdf):

\begin{equation}
\underset{x_1, x_2}{max} \ f(x_1, x_2) = -(1-x_1)^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
s.t \ \ \ 10(x_2 - {x_1}^2) = 0
\end{equation*}

with $\mathbf{x_0} = (-1.2, 1)$.  My algorithm stalls at $\mathbf{x_k} = (-1, 1)$, and $\mathbf{x^*} = (1, 1)$

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the 2nd derivative of $h$

Comment: @user251257 How (in general)?  $\mathbf{h}$ is a vector, $J$ is a matrix.  I'm confident the math is right, as I've checked other sources, this is more a of an algorithmic question that I haven't seen addressed yet.

Comment: Just google for SQP or sequential quadratic programming

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? The given example looks harmless. Have you update $\lamba$ correctly?

Comment: @user251257 I'll implement SQP and get back to you in a couple of days.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: $J(\mathbf{x}) \Delta \mathbf{x} = -\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$ is always under determined, if not $h(\mathbf{x})=0$ would give a set of discrete points. Something is wrong in your conclusion that from this condition alone $\Delta \mathbf{x} = 0$ follows.

Comment: @user251257 I implemented the algorithm taking into account the second derivative of $h$, and it did not help; however, what may be a solution is solving the unconstrained problem and to use that solution as your starting point $\mathbf{x}_0$ for your constrained problem.  It clearly worked for this problem because the optimal solution is the same in both the constrained and unconstrained case.

Comment: Please run the computation manually. There is no way that your old method could stall at $(-1,1)$. Concerning SQP, the initial guess for $\lambda$ have some importance, as the method is only local, if you haven't implemented globalization. But again, your given problem is rather harmless. You should run the computation manually to exclude the chance of programming error.